# Selecting all items individually in a list

Tags: python, maya

I was wondering if it is possible to re-select each and every item in the rsList?
I am citing a simple example below but I am looking at hundreds of items in the scene and hence below are the simplest form of coding I am able to come up with base on my limited knowledge of Python

```
rsList = cmds.ls(type='resShdrSrf')
# Output: [u'pCube1_GenShdr', u'pPlane1_GenShdr', u'pSphere1_GenShdr']
```

I tried using the following `cmds.select` but it is taking my last selection (in memory) - `pSphere1_GenShdr` into account while forgetting the other 2 even though all three items are seen selected in the UI.

Tried using a list and append, but it also does not seems to be working and the selection remains the same...

```
list = []
for item in rsList:
    list.append(item)
    cmds.select(items)
    #cmds.select(list)
```

As such, will it be possible for me to perform a `cmds.select` on each of the item individually?

Comment: So your saying: `rsList.select(list, replace=True)` does not select the items? Your loop in it self makes no sense tough you have no items variable. Is there a chance the objects names have changed in between.

Comment: @joojaa There are no change in the object names. The situation is like this : `rexShaderSrf` - they are custom shaders but for some reasons, unless I manual select each and every shaders, I am getting black renders. If I am using my above code, though it prints and highlights all 3 in hypershade, when re-rendering again, it only renders out the last selection in the list. So unless I have to re-select the other 2 manually, will I then be able to get the right render. And hence, I thought that there may be some ways to do a force selection again for all the items in the list

Comment: Sounds more like a affects network issue. In which case its not the selection that refreshes but he gui. Since gui does not refresh in your loop it does nothing. Redesign the node initialisation.

Comment: @joojaa What do you mean? The custom shader in itself was not created by me. Are there any ways in which I can resolve it within maya or via scripting?

Comment: Or perhaps are there any sort of documentation that I can read more about it?

Answer (score 0):

if your trying to just select each item:

```
import pymel.core as pm
for i in pm.ls(sl=True):
    i.select()
```

but this should have no effect in your rendering

Answer (score 0):

I think for mine, it is a special case in which I would need to add in `mm.eval("autoUpdateAttrEd;")` for the first creation of my shader before I can duplicate.

Apparently I need this command in order to get it to work